# Can I disable iOS PhotoLibrary usage setting from xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, phonegap-cli

I'm use phonegap to build ios app, after I tried to submit app via iTunes Connect, I got following message.

```
**Missing Info.plist key** - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

But My app just calling back-end API, I don't use iPhone's Photo Library, I do display html image tag and data is from API.

So is there a setting to disable the usage iPhone Photo Library at Xcode? I'm guessing that could fix my issue.

Comment: If you don't use the library this message wouldnt show up. Apparantly you are using it somewhere or calling the library from a third-party framework maybe if you have implemented that (?)

Comment: Thanks, I'm use phonegap, the app is just SPA javascript app and calling API. As far as I remember, don't have any code to use the PhotoLibrary from iOS.  However, I notice my phonegap is installed plugins cordova-plugin-camera, maybe that why somehow Xcode read it and think I'm actually use it because I have the plugin installed? I'm still not sure yet...

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/06d609cfa4871b4a2811f5a8f7f0a822733209b9/src/ios/CDVCamera.m  here is your problem. Please upvote if it solves your problem :P